# Shadows won't disable Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I am currently running Xubuntu 12.04. I dislike the menu and window drop shadows, therefore I went to Window Manager Tweaks, then navigated to the Compositor tab. Inside the compositor tab, I unchecked the areas that said "Show shadows under regular windows" and "Show shadows under popup windows." This worked for a few minutes, then the shadows reappeared. Is there another place I have to disable the shadows?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`WM Tweaks > Compositor` is indeed the correct place for disabling such effects. Try disabling compositing altogether in that window, to see if the undesired effects stop. And if they do, then reenable compositing and try to disable sequentially each of the options in that dialogue until you find the one that is offending. The disable that.

If nothing works, please provide a screenshot of the `WM Tweaks > Compositor` and of the issue that you're seeing.

Alternatively you can use [xfwm4-composite-editor](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=149523) that you can install from [ppa:rebuntu16/other-stuff](https://launchpad.net/%7Erebuntu16/+archive/other-stuff). It allows you to tweak more finely the compositor settings, as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/xfce4-composite-editor-easily-change.html). Once installed, access it from `Settings > Other`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Disabling the compositor does indeed eliminate the effect. However disabling the options sequentially did not remedy this.

Comment: That is strange. Please provide some screenshots of the issue.

Comment: [LINK](http://i59.tinypic.com/ndr993.png)
and checking or unchecking any of those options does not change anything anymore. Maybe my compositor is messed up or out of date since this is a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04. Thanks for your help, by the way

Comment: What about a screenshot when compositing is disabled (preferably after a full reboot)?

Comment: [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/dg5mc6.jpg) This removes the shadows, but I do not believe the 3d graphics in video games would run well like this, plus I would also like to keep the opacity of my panels.

Comment: I'm actually naively suspecting that the 3d graphics video games + compositing enabled are actually causing the issues that you see. But I have no experience with that, though.

Comment: Are you saying the combination of having both a video game and the compositor are causing this problem? Because if that's the case, it started adding shadows undesirably before I even tried playing any games. Maybe I should try updating to latest version of XFCE?

Comment: Yes, this may help. Try 4.12 (still beta, unreleased) from https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12 .

Comment: I upgraded to 4.10 and was sadden to not see a difference.  I'd rather not use 4.12 for few of bugs and crashes. Could my AMD graphics card be potentially interfering?

Comment: EDIT: I was just able to fix the problem by using xfwm4-composite-editor

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect this. Feel free to accept it now that it solves your issue.